# C# unable to retrieve textbox field value on multi threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to retrieve the value of my textbox field in a threading class, but the value is always empty. I tried to check with a breakpoint on debugger, but it just shows that "The function evaluation requires all threads to run".

I found [this explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/) on MSDN, but still no luck on retrieving the textbox value on threading class.

Here is my Window Load to start the thread function:

```
//Read D6010 Status To Get Weight Value on D6020
ThreadStart readWeightRef = new ThreadStart(readWeightStatusThread);
Thread readWeightThread = new Thread(readWeightRef);
readWeightThread.Start();
```

Here is my Threading Class Code:

```
public void readWeightStatusThread()
{
    string readStatus = (string)txtD6010Status.Invoke(new Func<string>(()=> txtD6010Status.Text));`

    while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(readStatus);
    }
}
```

Any way to resolve this?

Comment: you start the thread in the load event? is the textbox text already set in the constructor?

Comment: Is the field definitely populated before `Load` is called? Also, move the string assignment into the loop (I assume that is just for test purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem that you read value from the text box only once (in the Window Load) when it's still empty and don't try to read it again.

Try updating your worker thread to something like this

```
    public void readWeightStatusThread()
    {
        while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
        {
            string readStatus = (string)txtD6010Status.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => txtD6010Status.Text));
            MessageBox.Show(readStatus);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a private variable (static?) that gets updated on the OnTextBoxTextChanged then access the private variable value instead. You shouldn't access UI controls through threads as UI controls will ALWAYS be on the main thread so you're bound to get issues accessing UI controls from threads.  For reading a private global variable though this shouldn't cause too many issues.

Like this:

```
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someGlobalVariable = ((TextEdit)sender).Text;
}
```

If you need to update a UI control, like your TextBox on a thread - you need to check if the thread matches the UI control thread (main thread) like this:

```
private delegate void TextBoxDelegate(TextBox textBox, string text);

private void SetTextBox(TextBox textBox, string text)
{
    if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox.Invoke(new TextBoxDelegate(SetTextBox), textBox, text);
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.Text = text;
    }
}
```